# How can I process clear avocado oil with a pleasant scent, and how can I dry it faster?

Tags: flavor, oil, smell, color, avocados

I am processing my oil by cold press. I have to dry it first. I have three challenges:

1. The color of my oil is darker than intended.
2. My oil has a very strong smell.
3. I am seeking a cheaper and faster method for drying.

The dark oil is not appealing. Therefore I am seeking advice on how to achieve an appealing color. Also, are there alternative, natural scents that I can add to defuse the strong scent or remove it altogether? Lastly, any advice on a faster and cheaper drying methods?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please give us more information. E.g., you ask for a cheaper and faster method for drying. We need to know what you are doing now in order to answer. Any other details or info you can give about your process may help us to give you better answers. Additionally, the answers to this SA question, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11304/how-do-i-press-avocadoes-to-make-avocado-oil, may help.

Comment: Currently after skinning and removing the pit, I dry the flesh under the sun, the process takes 6 - 14 days. I process the dried material through a cold press system.