# To make avocado oil, how ripe do your avocados need to be?

Tags: oil, avocados

I'm interested in making pure avocado oil.  (No additives).  I plan to do this in a recipe that was posted on StackExchange here: [How do I press avocadoes to make avocado oil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11304/how-do-i-press-avocadoes-to-make-avocado-oil) ([Anthony Njoka's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40062/17272).

My question is about the necessary ripeness of the avocados.  It would make things very convenient if I could pick the avocados before they are ripe.  They sit on my table a considerable amount of time before they are ready for guacamole, and when the tree decides it's ready to give up its fruit, I get hundreds of unripe avocados.  Making avocado oil seems like the perfect solution.

Comment: In an answer to the referenced Stack Exchange question, a respondent said "ripe", which to me means not rock hard, or as you say, unripe.  I suspect you will have to let your unripe ones soften before you  start.  Good luck.  I'm guessing that you would want them to be as 'eatable' ripe as you can get them for this, but I am not posting this as an answer, because I think ripeness is a subjective value that may not be objective enough for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure which kind of technology you are going to use to press the avocado oil, but if you want pure and more healthy oil for cooking or cosmetic utilization, I recommend the [hydraulic cold press](http://www.simecoilpress.com/products/hydraulic-oil-press) process. Cause physical press will keep the nutrients of oil better.

Back to the question you asked, when hydraulically pressed, the ripeness of avocado greatly affects the final oil yield. The riper the fruit, the higher the oil yield. If you want to maximize the oil yield, just wait patiently be fore the fruit is completely ripe.

Answer (score 1):

https://m.wikihow.com/Make-Avocado-Oil. They need to be ripe. We picked them from under the tree so as no to run over them with the lawn mower. If you can smash it with your hand it's too ripe. If the seed "pops" out when halved, it's just right.
 Less ripe ones can work, but take longer to process.