Any advice on making avocado oil using my new dehydrator?
I've seen various 'dry naturally' methods and various 'mix with coconut oil' but since a) I have a new dehydrator and b) I want pure avocado oil, any suggestions would be helpful. For instance;

If I want say 16 oz of oil how many medium sized avocados would I want?
How ripe should I let them get?
How long would I dehydrate and at what temp? My current understanding is I want around 50c/122f but can't get a really good answer on how long. Some people say dry it some people say not.

My plan is to store in a mason jar and use my new mason jar vacuum sealer each time I used it.

see: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11304/how-do-i-press-avocadoes-to-make-avocado-oil?rq=1
